# best practice for checkbox in mvc 2

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox

I am creating an mvc 2 pplication.
in my app i need to display a checkbox.
which is best practice to do that and why?

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxfor(m=>m.UseFTP) %>
or
<input name="UseFTP" id="UseFTP" type="checkbox"/>
```

also i have jquery script as shown below;

```
$('#UseFTP').change(function() {   
   if($('#UseFTP').attr('checked')==true)
    {
    alert("UseFTP Check box clicked");
    }
 });
```

but i am not getting any alert when i click the checkbox
when i use the following html code

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxfor(m=>m.UseFTP) %>
```

Comment: Did you debug your script? What did it show?

Comment: @bzlm How to debug script in mvc 2???

Comment: F5. :) Or do it in the browser. Both IE9 and Chrome have excellent JavaScript debugging facilities. If you didn't know there was such a thing as JavaScript debugging, perhaps you should take some time to research some core web topics before venturing further in your webby endeavours. I'm sure it will be well invested time!

Answer (score 2):

This

```
is(':checked')
```

instead of

```
is(:checked)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (not tested):

```
$('input#UseFTP').change(function() {   
  if($(this).is(:checked)){
    alert("UseFTP Check box clicked");
  }
});
```